# Node ssh2 library private key error

Tags: node.js, ssh

Getting the following error from the Node ssh2 module,

Error: Unable to parse private key while generating public key (expected integer for version)

I've logged the key and it looks perfectly okay, so what would cause this?

Relevant code

privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/config/id_rsa', 'utf8'),

Comment: How did you generate the private key?

Comment: @mscdex This guide https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: That tutorial generated a key that works for me. What version of OpenSSL do you have installed? Can you generate and post an unused private key that exhibits the same problem?

Comment: The keys work fine, I can ssh through terminal using them without issue. 

Maybe you can help me understand something as I'm not super familiar with all of this. Why does this require my private key? Shouldn't I be using my public key? Better yet, is there anyway to load the public key?

Comment: The private key is needed to be able to encrypt and decrypt the actual communications with the server. All SSH clients work this way. You *can* set `publicKey` in the options, but it shouldn't be necessary because the public key can be derived from the private key. I'd still like to get a copy of an unused key that is exhibiting the problem for you though so I can see what's wrong. If it's a bug in `ssh2` I'd like to fix it :-)

Comment: How do I generate a new key without overriding the old one?

Comment: The `ssh-keygen -t rsa` should prompt you for the path. If not, you can specify the path on the command line with `-f filename`: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f foo.key`.